# C# - timer1 interval from numericupdown

Tags: c#, timer, intervals, numeric

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = int.Parse(numericupdown1.Value.ToString()) * 1000;
    }
```

I want that the timer1's inverval, is exactly the same as the numeric shows.. So if the numeric show the number: 5, i want the timer's invertval to be 5000 = 5 seconds..
Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you debug and checked? any exception? Define `doesn't work`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the event `ValueChanged` of `NumericUpDown`:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
   timer1.Interval = (int) (numericUpDown1.Value * 1000);
}
```

Comment: @FeliceM not really, it's slower than I want :)

Comment: @KingKing King Thank you<3 , can i ask another question?.. How can i stop a timer, after messagebox is appeared?

Comment: @user2783959 when do you want to show your `MessageBox`? just place the code `timer1.Stop()` after the `MessageBox.Show`. To register the `ValueChanged` event handler, you can do this: `numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += numericUpDown1_ValueChanged;`

Answer (score 0):

Do not user ToString() simply use convert

```
timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown.Value) * 1000;
```

This must be on change event

Comment: @KingKing I didn't notice any difference, there is no change event on my numeric